# Who is the "Current User" when time based workflow email alert fires

Tags: visualforce, email-template, time-dependent-workflow

Who is the "Current User" when a time based workflow fires in the future? I have Entitlement Milestone email alerts scheduled in the future, and the "From" (on behalf of) appears to be selected randomly. I have seen instances where it is not the creator or owner of the Case record being alerted on, nor did that user ever own or edit the record (from what I can see in the history).

I reference the current user twice in the template, once as the from, and once in the body of the message. It is a VF email template, that looks like this:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate 
    subject="CASE: {!relatedTo.casenumber}  has exceeded 60% of SLA time"
    recipientType="User" 
    relatedToType="Case" >
<messaging:HtmlEmailBody >
   Please review and resolve. 
   {!relatedTo.Subject} Case {!relatedTo.CaseNumber} will exceed its SLA level on:<br/> 
   <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.casemilestones}" var="cm">
      <apex:outputfield value="{!cm.Milestonetype.name }" /> -
         <c:VFEmailDateTime date_time_value="{!cm.TargetDate}" />
   </apex:repeat><br/><br/>

   Submitting Agent: {!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}<br/>
   Case Owner: {!relatedTo.Owner.Name}  {!IF(relatedTo.Owner.Type=="Queue","Queue","")}
   <br/>
   To access the case, use this link: <br/>
   <apex:outputlink 
      value="!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140,
      FIND('.com',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+4)+relatedTo.Id}">
      {!relatedTo.CaseNumber}
    </apex:outputlink><br/>
</messaging:HtmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

This random user also appears on the "Submitting Agent" line.  I assumed it would be the user that caused the condition to be true for the milestone (and alert) to be queued.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge workflows are always run in context of user who triggered it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't particularly well documented, but from my investigations it will be the user that triggered the time based workflow (i.e. took the action that caused it to be queued) **unless** the user has been deactivated, in which case it will be the default workflow user.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_defaultuser.htm&language=en_US

The key section is:

> When the user who triggered the rule isn’t active, Salesforce displays
>   the username of the default workflow user in the Created By field for
>   tasks, the Sending User field for email, and the Last Modified By
>   field for field updates.