# Workflow rule (time based) that updates the status of a contract from "XYZ" to "Activated" does not flip the status

Tags: community, workflow, time-dependent-workflow, contracts

I am writing a simple workflow rule (time based) that updates the status of a contract from "XYZ" to "Activated" on contract start date but it does not flip the status when it fires off.

I have another workflow rule that updates the status of a contract from "Activated" to "Expired" on contract end date and that works.

Is this something related to Salesforce where it does not allow contract activation through workflow rule or am I missing something?

Comment: what is your time trigger criteria? May be you have set it after some days to update the field?

Comment: (1) check the [running user for the time-based workflow](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/70099/2602) and compare said user's privileges per Help doc: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contract_activate.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I tried setting it to Draft vs Activated and that worked. However, it does not go to Activated.

Comment: Trigger criteria is an hour after start date.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The contract had to be in Draft status before I tried to move it to Activated status from the 'XYZ' status.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that Contract status can be changed to 'Activated' status via workflow field update.

**For sake of testing create a workflow rule like this:**
Rule criteria - contract Start Date not empty
Evaluation criteria - Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

And create immediate workflow action to update this status field to 'Activated'. You will get to know the result.

I am sure you are missing something. Can you check the rule condition of the workflow, any other updates via other processes or workflows or trigger.

Comment: I tried setting it to another status - Draft, and that worked. Activated however, did not.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The contract had to be in Draft status before I tried to move it to Activated status from the 'XYZ' status.

Comment: Is the issue solved?